# C language help:How to store strings from a .txt file into a character array? This .txt file is read from a command line argument btw.

Tags: c, encryption, command, arguments, line

I need to create a program that will read in a .txt file using the command line arguments and then encrypt the message in that txt file.

I used pointer to open the txt  file and I opened it successfully. But I need to store the message (consists of many paragraphs) into an array of single characters so that I can start my encryption.

For example, if the message is: I love dogs

I want to store that message into an array of characters such as:

```
 char word[5000];
 char word[0] = I;
 char word[1] = l;
 char word[2] = o;
 etc....
```

I tried to use a for loop to store the message into single character array, but when I tried to print out the array it does not show on my command line.

How can I store the message from the .txt file into a single character array?

this is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
int a;
printf("The number of arguements is :%d \n", argc);

for(a=0; a<argc; a++)
{
        printf("argc %d is %s \n",a, argv[a]);
}
```

//This section uses file pointer to read from a text file and then display it

```
printf("\n");
char * fname= argv[1];
FILE *fptr= fopen(fname, "r");
char word[5000];
int c;
if (fptr==0)
    {
        printf("Could not open file\n");
    }else
        {
            printf("FILE opened successfully \n");

        }

while (fgets(word, 5000, fptr) !=NULL)
{
    printf("%s \n", word);
}


fclose(fptr);
```

Comment: Your code worked for me... I am assuming that there is an `#include <stdio.h>` in the actual code that is missing in this code snippet. That is the only thing that I did that I don't see here.

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop uses fgets that is intended to read line by line.  If you want an array of characters that represents the bytes of the file, use fread.  First you'll need to know how big the file is; use stat or fstat for that.

```
 #include <stat.h>
 struct stat statbuf;
 int FS;
 char* buffer
 if (fstat(fileno(fptr),&statbuf)){
    ... handle error
 }
 FS = statbuf.st_size;
```

Then, for the file size now in FS, allocate some bytes

```
 buffer = (char*) malloc(FS)
```

Then read the contents

```
 fread(buffer, 1, FS, fptr)
```

Comment: Minor: Why use `int` for `FS` ?  `.st_size` is type `off_t` and `fread` expects `size_t`